# Examine the content of created plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

In my program I store some data in a plist. The plists content changes during user activities. Is there any option to examine the content of such created file in xcode?

Comment: I think it's possible to access the created plist from iTunes if it is located in the app's `Documents` directory. You don't even need Xcode.

Comment: I don't see them in Itunes

Comment: @userXXX Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to turn on document sharing. Set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in `Info.plist` to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the plist from a device, you can use Xcode's "Organizer", choose "Devices" tab, and then you can download the data associated with a particular app there:
[image]

When you download the `xcappdata` file, you can <kbd>control</kbd>-click on the file and choose "Show Package Contents" to navigate to the various folders in the app's sandbox.

Or if running the app on the simulator, you can navigate to "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" and see the files there. If you don't see your "Library" folder, you can execute the following from the Terminal command line:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```